# App crashes when I swipe left to delete a Cell

Tags: ios, swift

When I run my app every time I swipe left to delete my app crashes and it points me to the Thread 1: signal **`SIGABRT`**"  I believe this is the part of my code that is causing it.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
          allItems[indexPath.section].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
          tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
          let newData = DataItem(title: "New Data", subtitle: "", imageName: nil)
          allItems[indexPath.section].append(newData)
          tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
      }

      override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

        if editing {
          tableView.beginUpdates()

          for (index, sectionItems) in allItems.enumerate() {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sectionItems.count, inSection: index)

            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
          }

          //tableView.beginUpdates()
          tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
          tableView.endUpdates()
        } else {
          tableView.beginUpdates()
}
```

Comment: are you updating your tableView source array?

Comment: Please post the complete error message and stack trace from your console.

Comment: In debug mode which is the line with error?

Comment: tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

Comment: I added the breakpoint and that's where it shows

Comment: Please add the error message. Try using `begin` and `endupdates` when delete the row

Comment: I would guess one of your problems is you're not updating `numberOfRowsInSection` when you're deleting. If you want a good answer, you'll want to print out the console log of the crash and post the methods you use to update your `tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        allItems[indexPath.section].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        let newData = DataItem(title: "New Data", subtitle: "", imageName: nil)
        allItems[indexPath.section].append(newData)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: although this may help, the OP may not want to _reload_ all data... and the update should be more sophisticated than a massive 'reboot'.